# SBCL pass param from command line

Tags: unix, common-lisp, sbcl

In bash if I do "foo.sh x", then x can be used in bash by calling $1.

If I want to do the same with lisp, "script.lisp x" what can I use/call to get x as a param instead of $1.

Example

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
(if (eql intp $1)
   (+ $1 $1)
   (format t "~&not a valid int")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on your particular Lisp implementation. For SBCL, as you can find in the [User Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Command_002dline-arguments), the variable `sb-ext:*posix-argv*` contains the command line. So eg. `(nth 1 sb-ext:*posix-argv*)` would give you the first parameter.

Comment: For something more portable it may help to check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252130/574033